# org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction cannot be cast to

Tags: java, hibernate, thread-local

I have this class TransactionManager:

```
public class TransactionManager {

    private static ThreadLocal<Transaction> currentTransaction;

    public static Session getCurrentSession() {
        if(currentTransaction == null) {
        currentTransaction.set(
            HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction());
        }
        return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void rollback() {
        currentTransaction.get().rollback();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
        currentTransaction = null;
    }

    public static void beginTransaction() {
        currentTransaction.get().begin();
        // HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
        // currentTransaction = null;
    }

    public static void commit() {
        currentTransaction.get().commit();
        HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
        currentTransaction = null;
    }
}
```

and the error occurs at beginTransaction();  I've never user a ThreadLocal and I don't really know why I get this error. Without using a ThreadLocal **it works fine**. The reason I use a ThreadLocal is because I need a different session for every user(I want to create an application like Messenger).

Full error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: 
org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction cannot be cast to 
com.util.TransactionManager
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace instead of the "Full error:"?

Comment: I fix the problem. I don't need the method beginTransaction() because the transaction is started here : currentTransaction.set(
            HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().beginTransaction());  Also I forgot to instantiate the currentTransaction : currentTransaction = new ThreadLocal<Transaction> in getCurrentSession method before currentTransaction.set(...)